# $f(y)=\sup \{\lambda\in\Bbb R \mid y+\lambda1\in Y\}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Please help me with this:

> Let $Y\subset \Bbb R^n$ satisfying
>
> - $Y\cap\Bbb R_+^n=\{0\}$,
> - $Y$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$, and
> - $y-x\in Y$ for all $y\in Y$ and $x\in \Bbb R^n_+$.
>
> Let $1\in \Bbb R^n$ is unit vector. For $y\in \Bbb R^n$, let $f(y)=\sup \{\lambda\in\Bbb R \mid y+\lambda1\in Y\}$.
>
> Show that
>
> (i) If $(y_k)\subset \Bbb R^n$ is a convergent sequence, then $(f(y_k))\subset \Bbb R$ is bounded.
>
> (ii) $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous.

I have tried arguments like $(y_k)$ is bounded and cauchy, but I feel really stuck!

Comment: In case if $Y$ is convex set, you can easily prove $f$ is concave and finite So it is continuous .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $f$ is 1-Lipschitz continuous (wrt the max norm):

$Y$ intersects the positive standard cone precisely in the origin and contains the negative standard cone. So for each $y\in R^n$ the set $\{\lambda : y+\lambda 1 \in Y\}$ is an interval of the form $(-\infty,f(y))$. Taking $y'$ as starting point we have $y'+(f(y)-\|y-y'\|)1 =y'-y-\|y-y'\| 1 + (y+f(y)1)\in Y$ which shows that $f(y') \geq f(y) - \|y-y'\|$. By symmetry you get Lipscitz continuity from which the rest follows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please prove that $f(y_k)$ is bounded in part (i)? I can't prove that it is bounded below. I can see that $f(y_k)$ is bounded above since $y\ge y'$ implies $f(y)\le f(y')$

Comment: If you have arrived at $f(y')\leq f(y) + \|y-y'\|$ (where $\|x\|=\sum_i |x_i|$ is the max norm) then exchanging $y$ and $y'$ you get the reciprocal inequality and then $|f(y)-f(y')| \leq \|y-y'\|$ which gives the rest.